# How to style an input:invalid of a certain class?

Tags: css, html

So I've been having this problem for a while now, and I just can't figure out why it isn't working. I want to use html5 validation to validate my form, but only show a pink background on invalid inputs AFTER clicking on a button.

```
.submitted input:invalid {
   background-color: pink;
}
```

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pyMz/17/) here representing the problem I have.

Why is this CSS selector not working? Is there any other way to achieve this?
If I remove the .submitted and just leave the input:invalid, it works instantly, but I want the validation to execute only AFTER I click the button.

I'm certain the script works, as I can see the class being added to my inputs via firebug, but the styling infuriatingly stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you simply looking for the following? Pardon if I misunderstood your question.

```
input.submitted:invalid {
   background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Yes, yes exactly.
I thought I might just be doing the selector wrong, but I couldn't find how to do it correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For starters I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your jsfiddle. 
Firstly, inorder to assess whether a field is invalid, you need to do some validation then say, add a class to the input to say if it's invalid.
Seeing as you're using jQuery, I'll give you an example using javascript.

```
$('form'/*could supply a name like [name="name"]*/).submit(function(event){
    if($('input[name="firstName"]').val().length<3)$('input[name="firstName"]').addClass('error');
    event.preventDefault();
}
```